# Low-power ESP32 + LoRa with deep sleep mode (TTGO LoRa32 OLED Board V1.0)

Tags: c++, arduino, microcontroller, esp32, lora

I'm trying to transmit from one ESP32 LoRa node to another one in low-power mode and in compliance with european regulations.

ESP32 board: TTGO LoRa32 OLED Board V1.0 ([here](https://it.banggood.com/2Pcs-Wemos-TTGO-LORA32-915Mhz-ESP32-LoRa-OLED-0_96-Inch-Blue-Display-p-1239769.html?rmmds=search&cur_warehouse=CN) and [here](https://github.com/CaptIgmu/Arduino/tree/master/esp32/TTGO_LoRa32_OLED/)).

Below the LoRa sender sketch I wrote:

```
/*
 * LoRa (low-power) sender for IoT projects
 *  
 * Tested on a TTGO LoRa32 OLED Board V1.0 
 * 
 * Based on the LoRa examples and the board 
 * documentation
 * 
 * More on the deep sleep with timer wake up: 
 *  
 *    Examples > ESP32 > Deep Sleep > TimerWakeUp sketch
 *    
 *    
 * ERC Recommendation
 * h1.4 frequency band requires <= 1% duty cycle and 25mW (14 db) maximum power
 * => 36 seconds every hour (so: 1 sec transmitting, 99 secs idle) 
 * 
 * 
 * Created 11 June 2019
 * by DP 
 *    
 */
 
#include <SPI.h>   // allows communication with SPI devices 
#include <LoRa.h>
#include <SSD1306.h>   // provides API to work with OLED displays

// defines the pins used by the transceiver module
#define SS 18   // GPIO18 - SX1278's CS   - LoRa radio chip select
#define RST 14   // GPIO14 - SX1278's RESET   - LoRa radio reset
#define DI0 26   // GPIO26 - SX1278's IRQ   - IRQ pin

#define BAND 868E6   // EU   - Italy

// deep sleep 
#define uS_TO_S_FACTOR 1000000  // conversion factor for micro seconds to seconds 
#define TIME_TO_SLEEP  5        // time ESP32 will go to sleep (in seconds)   - 99 for (about) 1% duty cycle  


// an object of class SSD1306 
// first parameter: the I2C address of the display
// second parameter: the number of the SDA
// third parameter: the SCL pin
SSD1306 display(0x3c, 4, 15);

// stores the data on the RTC memory so that it will not be deleted during the deep sleep
RTC_DATA_ATTR int bootCount = 0; 
RTC_DATA_ATTR int pckCounter = 0;   // sending packet number...

 
void setup() {   
  Serial.begin(115200);   // initializes serial data transmission  
  while(!Serial);   // waits for serial port to connect 

  Serial.println("LoRa low-power Sender");
  
  pinMode(16, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(16, LOW);   // sets GPIO16 low to reset the OLED
  delay(50);
  digitalWrite(16, HIGH);   // while the OLED is running, GPIO16 must go to high  
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);   // sets the onboard LED low 
  
  // LoRa transceiver module setup 
  LoRa.setPins(SS, RST, DI0);   // overrides the default CS, reset, and IRQ pins used by the library

  // initializes the transceiver module with a specified frequency
  while (!LoRa.begin(BAND)) {   // LoRa.begin returns 1 on success, 0 on failure
    Serial.println(".");
  }

  // changes the spreading factor to 12 -> slower speed but better noise immunity
  LoRa.setSpreadingFactor(12);   // ranges from 6-12, default is 7 

  // changes the sync word (0xF3) to match the receiver
  // the sync word assures you don't get LoRa messages from other LoRa transceivers  
  LoRa.setSyncWord(0xF3);   // ranges from 0-0xFF     
 
  // LoRa.setTxPower(txPower);   // defaults to 17

  // initializes the display by calling the init method of the display object 
  display.init();   // receives no arguments and returns void

  // display.flipScreenVertically();   // LCD is broken!
  display.setFont(ArialMT_Plain_16);   // sets the current font
  display.drawString(0, 0, "Initialization");   // x, y, message to show
  display.drawString(0, 16, "completed");
  display.display();
  delay(1500);   // small delay so that the user can read it  

  Serial.println("LoRa init completed");    

  //Increments boot number and prints it every reboot
  bootCount++;
  Serial.println("Boot number: " + String(bootCount));

  sendData();   // sends the data...

  // deep sleep
  esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup(TIME_TO_SLEEP * uS_TO_S_FACTOR);
  Serial.println("Setup ESP32 to sleep for every " + String(TIME_TO_SLEEP) + " Seconds");
  Serial.println("Going to sleep now");
  Serial.flush();   // waits for the transmission of outgoing serial data to complete 
  esp_deep_sleep_start();   // enters deep sleep with the configured wakeup options
}

void loop(){
  // this is not going to be called
}

// sends the data to the receiver
void sendData() {
  
  Serial.print("Sending packet: ");
  Serial.println(pckCounter);

  display.clear();   // clears the display
  display.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGN_LEFT);
  display.drawString(0, 0, "Sending ");
  display.drawString(0, 16, "packet: " + String(pckCounter, DEC));
  display.display();
  
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);   // LED is ON during transmission

  // sends the LoRa packet to the receiver
  LoRa.beginPacket();
  LoRa.print("hello ");
  LoRa.print(pckCounter);
  LoRa.endPacket();
  
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);   // turns the LED off after transmission

  pckCounter++;
}
```

The sketch runs without errors (the code on the shop's page contains some errors, so I encourage you to use this one just to play with it). My questions:

- I forgot to initialize the SPI communication:

  `SPI.begin (SCK, MISO, MOSI, SS);`

  But nevertheless, it worked anyway. I didn't expect it. My **first question** is: what am I missing?
- I live in Europe. ERC Recommendation document says that h1.4 frequency band (I'm transmitting at 868 Mhz) requires <=1% duty cycle and 25mW (14db) maximum power. This means that I can transmit for 36 seconds every hour (let's say that I transmit for 1 sec and then the ESP32 'sleeps' for 99 seconds). I can achieve that writing (it's not the more accurate way but it should work):

  `#define TIME_TO_SLEEP  99`

  What about the erp? Let's say that the antenna has a 2db gain, so I can set the transmission power to 12db (12db + 2db -> 14db, great. It's ok!):

  `LoRa.setTxPower(12);`
- My **second question**: am I right (about both settings)? Am I missing something?
- **Last question**: please, feel free to give me any (if you have) feedback/suggestion to improve this sketch!

Answer (score 4):

That looks good, have you tested the power consumption during deep sleep? I've got the same board (TTGO ESP32 LORA with the OLED), and get about 38-50mA when awake, and 10mA during sleep. You can try `LoRa.end()` and `LoRa.sleep()` after you've finished sending to send the chip to sleep, but I'm not sure how much power this saves.

There are some discussions [going on here](https://github.com/Heltec-Aaron-Lee/WiFi_Kit_series/issues/6) about further ways to drop the power, but I've not been able to get it below 10mA for the TTGO.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your answer. I didn't try .end() and .sleep(). The deep sleep mode should save more power (I read a few uA in some discussions) since 'the only parts of the chip which can still be powered on are: RTC controller, RTC peripherals, and RTC memories' - [here](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/system/sleep_modes.html). 

I didn't test power consumption during deep sleep yet (I have not the 2-pin battery connector - currently I'm powering up the board via USB; so I will check as soon as possible).

Comment: Using the 2 pin battery connector I get a really poor power consumption of like 40mA, if you use a Low dropout 3.3v regulator, you can power the board straight off the 3.3v pins which gets me down to 10mA

Comment: Thank you, I'll try with the regulator.

Comment: Very good answers - thanks for sharing! Found this post as I am currently running into the same issue with my LoRa sensor module based on the TTGO v1 board. Are there any new results?

Comment: @Schmitzi Sorry, unfortunately, no new results. Glad that my post was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

In general, I have bad experience with LilyGo products and low current. I tested several of them (not the LoRa one) and usually they draw 1mA at minimum. I think the truly powersaving sensor can be made from Atmel LoRa node like [this](https://www.banggood.com/868MHz-LoRa-Radio-Node-V1_0-Wireless-IOT-Lora-Module-RFM95-SX1276-ATmega328P-3_7-12V-uFL-Antenna-Internet-of-Things-FZ3338-p-1636480.html?utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_organic&gmcCountry=CZ&utm_content=minha&utm_campaign=minha-cz-en-pc&currency=CZK&cur_warehouse=CN&createTmp=1&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_bgs&utm_content=sxxx&utm_campaign=ssc-cz-en-all-0926&ad_id=468344621658&gclid=Cj0KCQiA-OeBBhDiARIsADyBcE7kVHD_IMS6vhxhGhF79RAYTa7ar_R72PVNKV1Hw6HnJP7QdgndvPIaAtblEALw_wcB).

Added: Just for your information, I have testing rig (868MHz LoRa Radio Node V1.0) that sends LoRa message every hour and it is running for months on battery. Now after more than 3 months the battery drop is about 0.25V.

Answer (score 0):

Very nice, looks very similar to my sketch. I think the battery connector is using a low-drop regulator but this will still consume milliamps.
As I am currently evaluating an testing alternatives: Did you ever try to directly power the board with the GND/3V3 connectors? Using a standard 3.7V LiPo battery and some suitable Schottky diode to generate a voltage drop of about 0.2V should work fine to stay below 3.6V even with a full battery.